# Wrong colors inside tmux

Tags: terminal, colorscheme, tmux

In vim without tmux:
[image]

In vim with tmux:
[image]

- Color in Vim is 'default'
- My .vimrc has nothing related to colors.
- My .tmux.conf is empty.
- My .bashrc is untouched.
- I am using gnome-terminal with a custom color pallete.

Any help, please.

Answer (score 3):

Term creates new terminals with 
`TERM=screen-256color`

Put this in your .bashrc to fix the issue

`export TERM=xterm-256color`

**EDIT:** 
As pointed out in the comments, you should probably run `echo $TERM` when you are not in tmux, then set `export TERM=` to whatever the output of echo was.

Comment: This is not 100% correct, `TERM=xterm-256color` would break several keys on `rxvt` based terminals (and a good amount of people use `urxvt` for example).  OP should find the correct `TERM` setting for his terminal (the OS probably chooses a sensible one already) and only then add it to `.bashrc` so it will be used within `tmux`

Comment: @grochmal good point, updated the answer